# APIListView returns ids instead of values

Tags: django

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text="Enter a brief description of the book")

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_death = models.DateField('died', null=True, blank=True)

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title', 'author', 'summary')

class BookAPIListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    queryset = Book.objects.all()

urlpatterns += [
    path('api/books/', views.BookAPIListView.as_view(), name='api_books')
]
```

I am trying to write an API to return the title, author and the summary of the book. However, since the author of the book is the foreign key, it returns an id instead of the name of the author. What is the simple way to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the `BookSerializer` to serialize the `Author` as well, and thus represent this as "*nested*" data. We thus first define a serializer for the `Author` model:

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'date_of_birth')
```

and then you specify this serializer as the way to serialize the `author` field of the `Book` model:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    author = AuthorSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title', 'author', 'summary')
```

See the [documentation on *nested relationships* [Django-rest-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) for more information.